# Pyspark: Is it possible to convert a Java RDD to a Pyspark Dataframe without using python RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have a very complex pyspark job with a gigantic execution plan. It was previously taking ~20-30 minutes to just generate the plan. Caching wasn't really improving much in terms of planning time.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@hareesha1906/apache-spark-large-query-plans-54f3f3c9c7d3) that shows that caching does not actually remove the complexity of the plan (only the execution of it once it's resolved), and to split the plan into smaller pieces you can convert the dataframe into an RDD and back. Adding this saved us significant time, however we now have to deal with java <-> python serialization.

As I understand, a pyspark dataframe is a wrapper around a java dataframe, which is a wrapper around a java RDD. However, a pyspark RDD is a python object, and to convert between pyspark dataframe and python RDD requires sending the data between python and the JVM.

We can access the underlying java dataframe and rdd (and cache it) like so

```py
java_df = df._jdf
java_rdd = java_df.toJavaRDD()
cached_java_rdd = java_rdd.cache()
```

Is it possible to convert the resulting java RDD back into a pyspark dataframe? Or is this just a limitation of pyspark that is our punishment for not learning scala?

We tried the following:

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(cached_java_rdd, df.schema)
```

(doesn't work because java RDD is not iterable in python)

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([], df.schema)

jdf2 = cached_java_rdd.toDF()

df2._jdf = jdf2
```

(Apparently the java rdd is missing the toDF() method when we access it in python)